# Sliding menu from the bottom with half circle menu indicator?

Tags: android, menu, material-design

I want to implement this kind of menu on the bottom of the screen,
any tips, advise, sample codes?

the menu look like this when it's not activated.

[image]

sorry for my bad design :(

and that will look like this when it's got touched

[image]

I also want to change the who we are picture  which is right now the picture of a building, to the user's profile picture, if it's possible.

any help would be appreciated.